# JAXB 1.0 - can I compile using 1.7 JDK?

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2

I've inherited a pretty old Ant project, and been asked to 'upgrade it to java 1.7'.

Currently the project is 1.5, and has a mix of JAXB 1.0 and JAXB 2.0.

JAXB 2.0 bits upgrade fine, but when I try and upgrade the JAXB 1.0 bits to jdk1.7 I get errors such as;

```
Executing 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
'-classpath'
'C:\Users\xyz123\development\proj\lib-common\JAXB1\jaxb-xjc-1.0-ea.jar'
'com.sun.tools.xjc.Main'
'C:\Users\xyz123\development/proj/xml/dtd/doodah.dtd'
'C:\Users\xyz123\development/proj/xml/xjs/doodah.xjs'
'-d'
'C:\Users\xyz123\development/proj/packages/mis-reports/doodah/xml'
The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
not part of the command.

An error has occurred in the JAXB compiler.
Please submit a bug report to jaxb-feedback@java.sun.com
containing your input files as well as the output below.

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INITIAL_COLOR
    at javax.xml.bind.ValidatableObject.<init>(ValidatableObject.java:32)
    at javax.xml.bind.MarshallableObject.<init>(MarshallableObject.java:54)
    at javax.xml.bind.MarshallableRootElement.<init>(MarshallableRootElement.java:97)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.dtdx.DTDX.<init>(DTDX.java:57)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.dtd.DTD.convert(DTD.java:113)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.dtd.DTDParser.parse(DTDParser.java:92)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Main.doCompile(Main.java:85)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Main.compile(Main.java:106)
    at com.sun.tools.xjc.Main.main(Main.java:275)
```

Anyone got any ideas? I don't see much (if any) info on running jaxb 1.0 on a recent JDK.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is an impossible task because;

- JAXB 1.0 and JAXB 2.0 implementations are different, i.e. JAXB 1.0 requires javax.xml.bind.MarshallerObject which does not exist in JAXB 2.0
- JAXB 2.0 is provided in the 1.7 runtime
- JAXB 2.0 classes will always be present when trying to compile JAXB 1.0 against 1.7jdk

So unless there is some way to load the JAXB 1.0 runtime before the JDK runtime, I think I am stumped.

Answer (score 0):

It also looks like JAXB 2.0 turns element values (rather than attributes) into 'value' rather than JAXV 1.0 'content' so any code getters/setters will have to change to the corresponding getter/setter.